# Is there a way to batch update metadata in a group of files based on their file name?

Tags: windows, adobe, metadata

Lets say I have a list of files

```
File 001
File 002
File 003
```

Then I have a list that has the file name and the meta data title I want it to insert.

```
File 001 File Meta Data name 1 
File 002 File Meta Data name 2
File 003 File Meta data name 3
```

Is there a way to run a batch update so that they contain the updated metadata in adobe acrobat DC

Comment: Is there a way you can write code for me?

Comment: And when you mean `batch`, do you mean Windows Batch Script, or do you mean processing those files?

Comment: processing the files.

Comment: Then please remove the batch-file tag since batch-file is a Windows script, and does not mean processing files.

Comment: removed the tag